# What can I do to get a sound warning when fuel gets low?

Tags: mazda-3

In my Mazda 3 from 2018 I find it very weird that I do not get a warning when my fuel gets low.

What can be done about this (if anything?), because multiple times I got very scared with only a few kilometers left in the tank?

Is there something that can be changed or installed, or any other solution?

Comment: "Another solution" could be to carry a fuel can in the back, though it can be rather smelly, and a fire hazard if you are a smoker. But don't think about modifying the car, while it is still under warranty.

Comment: I have a Mazda 3 2012 and have driven 20km on the light. You should have a dash light some on when low. I can't see why you could not install something which makes sound between the ecu and the low fuel light but don't know if they make these. Try and get in the habit to refuel at 1/4 you will not be scared any more

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the low fuel light on a Mazda 3 comes on with approximately 50 miles/80km of fuel left. I'd always recommend filling up at around 1/4 tank in any car however, as this avoids disturbing the sediment that tends to build up in the bottom of the tank.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I should clarify. Yes, there is a light, but there's no sound. Given that it gives a lot of warning sounds for all other kinds of reasons, I did not find the possibility to have it make sound. Could mechanics influence that?

Comment: So you have .a working fuel gauge and a light that comes on when you get low? I don't see what the actual problem is, you just need to pay attention to those other 2 indications @PascalVKooten